# Windows Media Player not playing in KeyDown event

Tags: c#, windows-media-player

Windows Media Player is not playing when i need to play it in `KeyDown` event.
Here is my code:

```
if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
            {
                axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "mysoundfile.wav"
            }
```

Comment: Hi @hilalis! Have you tried using the full path to your file? e.g. `AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "C:\My Files\Movies\mysoundfile.wav"`. It would be helpful if you shared more of your code, please look at [example]

Comment: Also, try adding:  `axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play()`

Comment: My sound file is in debug folder☺

Comment: Another thought... maybe you are looking for `SoundPlayer` instead? `SoundPlayer mySound = new SoundPlayer("mysoundfile.wav");` `mySound.Play();`

Comment: But it gave error :( You can see image: hilalis.xyz/exception.PNG (yes, it is my website :))) )

Comment: I resolve the problem! Here is my code:  SoundPlayer splayer = new SoundPlayer();
            splayer.SoundLocation = @"spacevalidated.wav";
            splayer.Play();                                                                                              its my problem, i used "waw" but its "wav" so a small problem :)

Comment: Glad you fixed it!